# Issues with Discord JS Music Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, bots, discord.js

I am in the process of creating a Discord bot with JS, giving it management, auto role, etc. I just got to the music section of it and I can't quite figure out whats wrong.

I believe I have installed FFmpeg correctly, as I have access to it from within the terminal. I have also used npm to bring ytdl-core and opusscript into my program.

What this should do is make the bot join the chat, then play the Youtube link. Currently, I am not error checking the second argument as I just wanted to get it working initially. I have implemented several different instances of .toString() and String() however it always gives the same error listed below.

. The program still throws this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object

C:\Users\Thresio's PC\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\opusscript\build\opusscript_native_wasm.js:8
var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var
key;for(key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key))
{moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}Module["arguments"]=
[];Module["thisProgram"]="./this.program";Module["quit"]=function(status,toThrow) {throw
toThrow};Module["preRun"]=[];Module["postRun"]=[];var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var 
ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=false;var 
ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof 
importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof 
process.versions==="object"&&typeof 
process.versions.node==="string";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONM
ENT_IS_WORKER;ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var
scriptDirectory="";function locateFile(path){i
abort(TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type 
string. Received type object). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```

Here is my code for calling play:

```js
case 'play':

            function play(connection, message){
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: 'audioonly'}));

                server.queue.shift();

                server.dispatcher.on('end', function(){
                    if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);
                    }else {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                })
            }

            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send('You need to provide a link!');
                return;
            }

            if(!message.member.voiceChannel){
                message.channel.send('You must be in a voice channel to play music!');
                return;
            }

            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            })
            break;
```

If anyone could assist with this, I would be very grateful.

EDIT: I unfortunately never figured out my main issue, but I have now found code that works (unlike mine :/).
For anyone else having this issue, I suggest using the code [found here.](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/dicord-music-bot)
Works like a charm!

Comment: I have now also tried the solution from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571184/discord-bot-youtube-search-wait-for-answer-of-asynchronous-function
And still throws the same error above.

Answer (score 1):

You try play `message` , message its a discord colelction. You need use play args[number]

**REPLACE**

```java
if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection) {
    play(connection, message);
});
```

**TO**

```java
if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection) {
    play(connection, args[1]);
});
```

Comment: Same one as listed above, in the first "code" section of the question.

Comment: if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);

Change it too

Comment: Sorry for a delayed response. I changed it there and everywhere else but never figured out my issue. I have now deleted my play code, and used the code here instead [link](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/dicord-music-bot)
Unlike mine, it actually works. Thanks for the help anyway Cipher!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to fix your code. You needed to install these modules:

```
npm install discord.js ffmpeg fluent-ffmpeg @discordjs/opus ytdl-core --save
```

And run the script like this:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' node bot.js
```